# Class files (.java) inaccessable from Jar

Tags: java, android, jar

[I created a Jar file.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SPbhy.png)

When I use it in my project it seems to be able to find the Package name just fine but I can't use the classes within.

[Package name, but no classes after.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7MiN8.png)

Did I do something wrong when creating the Jar?
I ran "jar cvf Adapter.jar *".

Any suggestions would be a great help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A Java JAR file is supposed to contain compiled `.class` files, not `.java` source files.
You'll need to compile your files using `javac` and then use `jar` on the output.

Answer (score 0):

As NimrodArgov pointed out, your IDE (apparently) can't find the class because it does not exist as compiled `.class` file as it would be expected. The JAR package only contains the Java source files.

As far as I can see, there is no need for you to pack your classes into a `.jar` file either. Just make sure the containing folder structure is in your Java Classpath.